# Check file creator before loading to prevent tampering/corrupted data

Tags: c#, c++, digital-signature

**Informative**

I'm working on a project that loads a binary file from the disk. This file has a specific structure to store data and I need to protect this file from being loaded if the data was generated/tampered by third parties.

**Resume**

I have a file that I must check if the "creator" is me before loading.

**Project Specification**

1. The application that loads the file is written in C++.
2. The application that generates the file is written in C#.

**Question**

- What are my options to accomplish this?
- What libraries/algorithms to use?
- Can you provide me some steps or guides?

**Notes**

- I have Crypto++ linked to the C++ project if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a signing/certifying system wirth asymetric keys. The functionality is built in .Net. A Quick google search shows [this example](http://www.fryan0911.com/2009/04/c-how-to-sign-and-verify-digital.html) which looks legit.

Keep in mind though, that if you don't have the full control of the certification process (if your application is on a client's computer), someone might decompile the code to bypass the check.

Comment: but for doing this I must buy some type of certificate ? or I can generate my own and use it normally? Keep in mind that this is just internal checks.

Comment: Yes, you can generate your own certificates. For example using IIS: http://geekswithblogs.net/iupdateable/archive/2009/09/22/using-iis-to-generate-a-x509-certificate-for-use-with.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I was reading some papers about this and seems like it will work.

Answer (score 0):

quickly like that i would take a look at [LZMA SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) since the SDK support c++ and C# and just compress/encrypt the file

maybe there is a better solution, but this would be my first try

Comment: Compression/encryption is not a problem. What I really need is to check if the file is modified and/or generated by someone before being loaded. The file content can be 100% valid but it cannot be loaded if its modified/generated by someone.